# Error al comparar dos números en un script de bash

Tags: linux, bash

Estoy haciendo un script que le pones dos numeros y te dice si son diviisibles. Pero me da error.
Estoy haciendo un script que le pones dos numeros y te dice si son diviisibles. Pero me da error.
EL CODIGO DEL SCRIPT:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
#!/bin/bash



read -p "Numero 1: " num1

read -p "Numero 2: " num2

cero=0

$op=$(($num1%$num2))

if [$op -eq $cero] 

then

echo "ES DIVISIBLE"

else

echo "NO ES DIVISIBLE"

fi

/divisibles.sh

Numero 1: 4

Numero 2: 4

./divisibles.sh: línea 6: =0: orden no encontrada

./divisibles.sh: línea 7: [: falta un `]'

NO ES DIVISIBLE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `op` al inicializarlo va sin el `$`
- Te falta un `;` en el condicional `if`:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Numero 1: " num1
read -p "Numero 2: " num2

cero=0

op="$(( $num1%$num2 ))"

if [ "${op}" -eq "${cero}" ]; then
    echo "ES DIVISIBLE"
else
    echo "NO ES DIVISIBLE"
fi
```

Resultado:

```
$ bash numbers.sh 
Numero 1: 2
Numero 2: 1
ES DIVISIBLE

$ bash numbers.sh 
Numero 1: 1
Numero 2: 2
NO ES DIVISIBLE
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!!!!!

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido.

Comment: No hace falta el ";" si hay un salto de linea. Además, te falto mencionar el espacio entre los corchetes "[<espacio><expresión><espacio>]"

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser que tu problema sea que en vez de declarar la variable osea crearla la estas llamando como si ya existiera.
El codigo deberia quedar algo asi:

```
#!/bin/bash


read -p "Numero 1: " num1

read -p "Numero 2: " num2

cero=0#Aqui quitamos el dollar para que en vez de llamarla el programa interprete que la estas creando

let op=$num1%$num2#Igual aqui, he cambiado el comando a ver si asi te va

if [$op == $cero]; #Tambien pon el punto y coma importante que se nos habia olvidado XD. Pones el igual por si acaso tienes un problema de tipo de variables

then

echo ES DIVISIBLE

else

echo NO ES DIVISIBLE

fi
```

Dime si te funciona porque no lo he podido testear

Comment: No me funciona, sale el mismo error de antes:./divisibles.sh: línea 7: [0: orden no encontrada

Comment: linea 7:if [$op -eq $cero]

Comment: Ya no te da el error en la misma linea que antes?

Comment: Ahora te la da en la linea 7 no?

Comment: si  en la linea 7

Comment: Cambia el "-eq" por "=" y si te lo hace es porque te esta cogiendo las variable como si fuenen cadenas de texto y no enteros

Comment: edita la pregunta y añade una captura de pantalla a la pregunta del codigo y el error y asi lo veo meho

Comment: Ya lo he modificado

Comment: Ok copia mi codigo que he cambiado alguna cosa ahora entero y pruebalo a ver que tal puedes hacer ctrl + c ctrl + v al codigo entero

Comment: Me sigue dando el mismo error.

Comment: Pruba ahora mi codigo a ver que tal

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140030/discussion-between-jeus-jimenez-and-anthonyx82).

Comment: Nada no funciona

Comment: ./divisibles.sh

Numero 1: 4

Numero 2: 4

./divisibles.sh: línea 12: [0: orden no encontrada

NO ES DIVISIBLE

Comment: Pruebalo por ultima vez y si no te va aun yo me rindo XD pon la foto de la ejecucion en la pregunta He cambiado las comillas del echo ya que no son necearias